# Closure properties-show that language is contextfree

Tags: context-free-grammar

I have a question..Using the closure properties,I have to show that the language $\left \{ w\epsilon \left \{ 0,1 \right \}^{*}:w\neq 0^{m}1^{m},m\geq 0 \right \}$ is contextfree.Could you give me a hint how to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show this using closure properties one has to start with at least one language known to be context-free. Here $K = \{ 0^n1^n \mid n\ge 0\}$ is a good choice.

You want to show that the complement of $K$ also is context-free, but alas context-free languages are not closed under complement. We can however write your language as the usion of (1) strings $0^m1^n$ with $n>m$ (2) idem with $n<m$ (3) strings not of the form $0^*1^*$.

Language (3) is regular, languages (1) and (2) can be obtained from $K$ using simple language operations.

Comment: Is it maybe $(1)\cap (2)=K$ ?or not?

Comment: No $(1)\cap(2)=\varnothing$, but that is not the point.

Comment: What language operations do you mean that I have to use for (1) and (2) ?

Comment: Assuming $m>n$ then $0^m1^n = 0^{m-n}\cdot 0^n1^n$.

Comment: So,is (2) the union of the languages: $\{0^{m-n}:m-n>0\}$ and $K$ ?

Comment: Dear @evinda, I invite you to review the language operations. Concatenation, not union. Also $\{0^m-n \mid m-n>0\}$ is better written as $0^+$.

Comment: So, $(2)=0^{+}K$ is contextfree, as contextfree languages are closed under the concatenation.
Similar,$(1)=1^{+}K$ is contextfree.
$(3)$ is regular.
So, the language is $(1)U(2)U(3)$ .
$(1)U(2)$ is contextfree,because contextfree languages are closed under the union. But,is the union of a contextfree with a regular language also contextfree?